# Is there any "helperclass" allowed in mvc / mvp pattern?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, mvp, android-mvp

I am programming with android studio and I am using the **mvp** (model view presenter) pattern.
But I have some broadcast receiver e.g. to know when the device is starting.
Also I have a class called **notificationhelper**, there I create the notification channels and define the exact messages.

Are these (bc and helper) classes allowed in the **mvp / mvc** pattern?

And are these classes model or more like presenter/controller?

I am not sure at all, so what would you say?

Comment: architectures are a way of structuring your code. it makes zero sense for an architecture to not allow a critical piece of functionality you need, that's like asking if you're allowed to use variables with a specific architecture

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Well I was sure i knew the answer. But if I search for MVP and MVC i never found any piece of text or picter that said:" hell yea, if u need some more classes, just do it"

Comment: why would that _not_ be allowed, if that wasn't allowed would all apps be forced into using a set amount of classes ? again, architectures are a way of structuring your code to create a loose coupling between your UI and your business logic, they aren't even rules, they are guidelines.